# How to debug Move Generation function?

Tags: engines, computer-chess

I'm writing a chess engine, and I'm testing that the move generator is working correctly using a perft() function.  In perft position 2 my engine appears to be 90 moves short at ply 2.  How do authors of other engines then debug their engines?  Is there a full list of perft moves available online somewhere?

The obvious issue with using an established engine to enumerate the moves is if there's a bug in the move generation function in the established engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The obvious issue with using an established engine to enumerate the moves is if there's a bug in the move generation function in the established engine.

Stockfish is always perfectly correct.

Goto https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/master/src/search.cpp, add a `std::cout` in `perft()`. Recompile, and then run perft. Redirect your results to a text file.

Sort the results with: `sort SFMoves.txt > SortedSFMoves.txt`.

Similarly, repeat for your generator, sort it and then compare with Stockfish.

Common mistakes:

- En-passpant
- Underpromotion
- Promote with a capture

Please check the special cases in your code.

Comment: Ok, I'm absolutely fascinated to see what I've missed - my assumption was that I'd be generating too many moves as I'm not preventing the moving of a piece that is pinned to the king yet.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I strongly recommend the use of the [perftree](https://github.com/agausmann/perftree) program. It compares the results of your `perft` function with the one implemented by Stockfish. This helped me a lot to debug my move generator.

For instance, if you run `perft(6)` and find out that, e.g., the number of moves from **a2a3** is larger/lower than it should be, you update the position by doing such move, and then you run `perft(5)`. You repeat this until you reach depth 1, where you can find out what kind of moves you are allowing (pseudolegal) or missing.